# Function for calculating working week in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a similar question posted, but did not quite get the answer I needed I have the following sql code which gets built up in a c# app... This code works fine, except for when the date range is bigger than 1 working week.  I need to edit the code so that when the CSIAchieved date falls into the next working week it is 'outside' of SLA.

When the Achieved date is within the same week as the Target date it is 'inside' SLA.

```
if (CSILOSDate.Length > 0) {
  sql += CSILOSDate + " as [CSITarget], " +
         CSIActualDate + " as [CSIAcheived], " +
         "CASE WHEN " + CSILOSDate + " IS NULL OR " + CSIActualDate + 
                   " IS NULL THEN 'Incomplete' " +
               "WHEN " + CSIActualDate + " 
                      <= DATEADD(DAY, 6-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, " +
                      CSIActualDate + "), " + CSIActualDate + ") " + 
                   "THEN 'Inside' " +
               "WHEN " + CSIActualDate + " <= " + CSILOSDate + 
                   " THEN 'Inside' " +
               "ELSE 'Outside' " +
          "END AS [CSIStatus] ";
}
```

Comment: Do you need to handle holidays?

Comment: no the user has said they will ignore holidays

Comment: If the user said that they will ignore holidays, that's an almost sure sign that you're going to have to handle holidays ;)

Comment: nope, i told them if it had to handle holidays it would be a full blown change request which means they would have to part with their cash... that tends to keep them quiet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add another Case as First Case

```
"Case When DateDiff(week, '" + CSIActualDate +
      "', '" + CSILOSDate + "') > 0 Then 'Outside'" 
+  --- then the rest of the cases ...
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest that you use parameterized queries.

Also, should this line:

```
WHEN CSIActualDate <= DATEADD(DAY, 6-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CSIActualDate), CSIActualDate)
     THEN 'Inside'
```

actually be:

```
WHEN CSIActualDate <= DATEADD(DAY, 6-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CSILOSDate), CSILOSDate)
     THEN 'Inside'
```

Comment: Yes, but in your code you're comparing the actual date to itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (CSILOSDate.Length > 0)
        {
            sql +=
                CSILOSDate + " as [CSITarget], " +
                CSIActualDate + " as [CSIAcheived], " +
                "CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(WEEK, " + CSILOSDate + ", " + CSIActualDate + ") > 0 Then 'Outside'" +
                "WHEN " + CSILOSDate + " IS NULL OR " + CSIActualDate + " IS NULL THEN 'Incomplete' " +
                "WHEN " + CSIActualDate + " <= DATEADD(DAY, 6-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, " + CSIActualDate + "), " + CSIActualDate + ") " +
                "THEN 'Inside' " +
                "WHEN " + CSIActualDate + " <= " + CSILOSDate + " THEN 'Inside' " +
                "END AS [CSIStatus] ";
```